# Retrieve multiple records as single record

Tags: join, sqlite

I am new to SQLite. I am using SQLite Manager Firefox add-on. I have created a database and a table. This table stores webcam recordings. Each record is a recording up to 3 min. I am trying to retrieve one record per continuous recording. If there is gap more than 3 min then it would be considered as a separate recording. Below is the script.

```
CREATE TABLE recordings ( 
    [key]          INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
    filename       VARCHAR(50),
    start_datetime DATETIME,
    end_datetime   DATETIME,
    deleted        BOOLEAN 
);

INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f1', '2013-08-26 00:00:00', '2013-08-26 00:03:00', 0);
INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f2', '2013-08-26 00:03:01', '2013-08-26 00:06:00', 0);
INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f3', '2013-08-26 00:06:01', '2013-08-26 00:09:00', 0);

INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f4', '2013-08-26 00:14:00', '2013-08-26 00:17:00', 0);
INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f5', '2013-08-26 00:17:01', '2013-08-26 00:20:00', 0);
INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f6', '2013-08-26 00:20:01', '2013-08-26 00:23:00', 0);

INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f7', '2013-08-26 00:30:00', '2013-08-26 00:33:00', 0);
INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f8', '2013-08-26 00:33:01', '2013-08-26 00:36:00', 0);
INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f9', '2013-08-26 00:36:01', '2013-08-26 00:39:00', 0);

INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f10', '2013-08-26 00:44:00', '2013-08-26 00:47:00', 0);
INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f11', '2013-08-26 00:47:01', '2013-08-26 00:50:00', 0);
INSERT INTO [recordings] ([filename], [start_datetime], [end_datetime], [deleted]) VALUES ('f12', '2013-08-26 00:50:01', '2013-08-26 00:53:00', 0);
```

The result should be like below,

```
recording1      2013-08-26 00:00:00     2013-08-26 00:09:00
recording2      2013-08-26 00:14:00     2013-08-26 00:23:00
recording3      2013-08-26 00:30:00     2013-08-26 00:39:00
recording4      2013-08-26 00:44:00     2013-08-26 00:53:00
```

I tried achieve the same using SQL Server using CTE but it is not supported in SQLite. Below is the CTE way,

```
with cte
as
(
select [KEY],start_datetime,end_datetime,1 as recodringno from [dbo].[recordings] where [KEY] =1
union all
select a.[KEY],a.start_datetime,a.end_datetime
,case when DATEDIFF(MINUTE,b.end_datetime,a.end_datetime)>3 then b.recodringno+1 else b.recodringno  end

as recodringno from 
[dbo].[recordings] a 
inner join cte b on a.[KEY]=b.[KEY]+1 

)
select 'recodring'+cast(recodringno as varchar(10)) as recodringno
,MIN(start_datetime)start_datetime,MAX(end_datetime) end_datetime from cte group by recodringno
```

I would appreciate your help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL Server query goes through the records recursively to find all recordings that belong to a single group.
Such a recursive construction is not possible in SQLite.

However, it is possible to find groups by inverting the check:
a record is the first one in a group (`r1`) if the difference to the previous recording (`r2`) is more than three minutes (or if there is no previous recording).
Once we have the start of a group, we can compute the end by finding the first following record (`r3`) whose difference to the next record (`r4`) is larger than three minutes (or which has no next record):

```sql
SELECT r1.start_datetime AS start,
       (SELECT MIN(r3.end_datetime)
        FROM recordings AS r3
        WHERE r3.start_datetime >= r1.end_datetime
          AND IFNULL((SELECT MIN(strftime('%s', r4.start_datetime))
                      FROM recordings AS r4
                      WHERE r4.start_datetime >= r3.end_datetime),
                     99999999999) - strftime('%s', r3.end_datetime) > 3*60
       ) AS end
FROM recordings AS r1
WHERE strftime('%s', r1.start_datetime) -
      IFNULL((SELECT MAX(strftime('%s', r2.end_datetime))
              FROM recordings AS r2
              WHERE r2.end_datetime <= r1.start_datetime),
             0) > 3*60
```

(This computes the gap as the difference between the end and the next start, which is just one second in your examples. You might want to reduce the 3*60 threshold.)